# To disable future dates using PhoneGap date picker

Tags: android, ios, cordova, datepicker

Is there a way to disable future dates using phonegap datepicker plugin? I know of an option to allow old dates, but I am not seeing anything for the future date? Developing an hybrid, and looking for an option to restrict on both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable such as options.max and set it to the taday date. Pass this argument to the handaleDate Method here is [Plugins](https://github.com/bikasv/cordova-android-plugins/tree/master/datepicker)...

```
function handleDates(elm, options) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var currentField = $(elm);
    var opts = options || {};
    var minVal = opts.min || 0;
    var maxVal = opts.max || 0;// Set this to Todays date

    var myNewDate = Date.parse(currentField.val()) || new Date();
    if(typeof myNewDate === "number") {
        myNewDate = new Date (myNewDate);
    }

    window.plugins.datePicker.show({
        date : myNewDate,
        mode : 'date',
        minDate: Date.parse(minVal),
        maxDate: Date.parse(maxVal)
    }, function(returnDate) {
        if(returnDate !== "") {
            var newDate = new Date(returnDate);
            currentField.val(getFormattedDate(newDate));
        }
        currentField.blur();
    });
}
```